# Chapter 3, question 20 part b of Spivak's Calculus 3rd edition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis

Suppose that $f(y)-f(x)\le(y-x)^2$ for all $x$ and $y$. (Why does this imply that $\lvert f(y)-f(x)\rvert \le (y-x)^2$ ?) .Prove that $f$ is a constant function. Hint: Divide the interval from $x$ to $y$ into $n$ equal pieces.

In the answer book, Spivak tried to prove that $$\lvert f(y)-f(x) \rvert \le \frac{(y-x)^2}{n}$$. Then he concludes that "therefore $f(y)=f(x)$ for all $x$ and $y$".

So my question is: **What is he trying to prove?** If he is trying to prove $f(y)=f(x)\forall x,y$, why does he make a hassle by trying to prove the inequality? It is very out of place. It makes no sense at all. I understand that he is trying to prove the inequality prove the question in the parenthesis, but we need to prove that $f(x)=f(y)$ $\forall x,y$.

**QUESTION 2**: Can you please help me the question in the parenthesis: $\lvert f(y)-f(x)\rvert \le (y-x)^2$?. Why is it so? We cannot take square and take root simply because $f(y)-f(x)$ can be negative. Let $f(y)-f(x)=-9$ and $(y-x)^2=8$ and you will see that square them will change the inequality ($81>64$)

I thank you very much for your answer. Spivak and the people who preceded him are truly genius, if not "monster".

Comment: I don't understand your question.Is there any step which you can't see why it logically follows from previous facts?

Comment: Regarding the question in parentheses: If $f(y)-f(x) \leq (y-x)^2$ for *all* $x$ and $y$, then simply interchange $x$ and $y$ to get $f(x)-f(y) \leq (x-y)^2 = (y-x)^2$.

Comment: Everything is clear to me, but after trying to prove the inequality, he concludes that $f(y)=f(x)$ for all $x$ and $y$. I do not understand what he is doing.

Comment: I thank you very much MrBungo. You are so smart. This helps with my question 2.

Comment: Regarding the main question, do you agree that if $x$ and $y$ are fixed, and $|f(y)-f(x)| \leq (y-x)^2/n$ for all positive integers $n$, then this implies that $f(x) = f(y)$?

Comment: @user138893 Take the limit as $n\longrightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Git Gud: Spivak has not discussed anything about limit so that will not do.

Comment: @Bungo: No, Mr.Bungo, I do not agree that it is so. What the hell? The inequality implies nothing about $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: @user138893: Consider a simpler problem. If I tell you that there is some real number $x$ with the property that $|x| < 1/2$ and $|x| < 1/3$ and $|x| < 1/4$ and so on, such that $|x| < 1/n$ for all positive integers $n$, then can $x$ be anything except zero?

Comment: @bungo: $x$ is very near to $0$, but it cannot be $0$. No I cannot accept that.

Comment: @user138893: If $x$ were nonzero, then $|x|$ must be a positive real number. But then it's possible to find some positive integer $n$ such that $0 < 1/n < |x|$. This is the so-called Archimedean property of the real numbers. Unfortunately, Spivak doesn't seem to mention this property until chapter 8, so there's apparently a logical gap. However, I hope that the property is intuitively clear.

Comment: @bungo: Oh my god, this is truly magical. I have read Archimedian property once in Rudin, but I cannot appreciate it until now. Oh my holy god !!! Bungo you are an expert.

Comment: @bungo: I just want to say : thank you very much Mr.Bungo. I thank you very much. If you had answered my question, I would have accepted yours.

Comment: @user138893: No problem, I'm glad I could help. Lee Mosher's answer is excellent, no need for me to add another one. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's suppose, as Spivak says, that you can prove the following inequality is true for all $x,y,n$:
$$|f(y)-f(x)| \le \frac{(y-x)^2}{n}
$$
Now let's hold the values of $x$ and $y$ constant. We may assume $x \ne y$ (because if $x=y$ then $f(x)=f(y)$ and we are done). So on the right hand side the numerator $(y-x)^2$ is nonzero, and since it is a square it is positive. We may therefore divide by $(y-x)^2$ and we get:
$$\frac{|f(y)-f(x)|}{(y-x)^2} \le \frac{1}{n}
$$
On the left hand side of this inequality we have a non-negative number which is constant (because $x$ and $y$ are being held constant, the numerator is non-negative, and the denominator is positive). This number is less than every fraction $\frac{1}{n}$ for all natural numbers $n \ge 1$. This implies that the left hand side equals zero:
$$\frac{|f(y)-f(x)|}{(y-x)^2}=0
$$
Now multiply by $(y-x)^2$ and you get
$$|f(y)-f(x)|=0
$$
and so
$$f(y)-f(x)=0
$$
$$f(y)=f(x)
$$
Since this is true for all values of $x,y$, we are done.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)-f(y)\le\frac{(x-y)^2}n\;\forall\;x,y\in\mathbb R\implies \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\le\frac{x-y}n\;\forall\;x,y\in\mathbb R$$
Take the limit $y\to x$ do you see $f'(x)=0\;\forall\;x\in\mathbb R$. So $f(x)$ is a constant function.

Comment: FYI, this problem appears in chapter 3, "Functions", which comes before limits (chapter 5) and derivatives (chapter 9).

Comment: Yes, so please could you answer it in a non-derivative way? I want to know the basic, the "classic" before delving into a real calculus.

Comment: @Bungo I didn't studied that book, so you cannot expect me to .........

Comment: @Aditya: I don't expect you to do anything in particular. :-) I just wanted to add the context which was not mentioned in the OP's question.

Comment: I appreciate very much for your answer.